# Android Sunshine onOptionsItemSelected MainActivity vs ForecastFragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm almost through Lesson 3 of the android Udacity tutorial and I noticed that we start our Intent for settings in the MainActivity class while we refresh and update our data in the ForecastFragment class. I was wondering why this was as I moved the settings "if statement" into ForecastFragment and everything worked the same.
Here's the two onOptionsItemSelected methods:
MainActivity:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

ForecastFragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        updateWeather();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

What's the differences between the two onOptionsItemSelected methods? Also, this is my first question on StackOverflow so if I made any mistakes please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

I also posted the entire code for MainActivity and ForecastFragment below:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

and here's ForecastFragment:

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

public ForecastFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        updateWeather();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source and
    // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
    mForecastAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                    new ArrayList<String>());

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String forecast = mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecast);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

private void updateWeather() {
    FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String location = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
            getString(R.string.pref_location_default));
    weatherTask.execute(location);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    updateWeather();
}

public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

    /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
     * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
     */
    private String getReadableDateString(long time){
        // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
        // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
        SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
        return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
     */
    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low, String unitType) {

        if (unitType.equals(getString(R.string.pref_units_imperial))) {
            high = (high * 1.8) + 32;
            low = (low * 1.8) + 32;
        } else if (!unitType.equals(getString(R.string.pref_units_metric))) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Unit type not found: " + unitType);
        }

        // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

        String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
        return highLowStr;
    }

    /**
     * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
     * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
     *
     * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
     * into an Object hierarchy for us.
     */
    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
            throws JSONException {

        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

        // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
        // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
        // properly.

        // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
        // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
        // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

        Time dayTime = new Time();
        dayTime.setToNow();

        // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
        int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

        // now we work exclusively in UTC
        dayTime = new Time();

        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];

        // Data is fetched in Celsius by default.
        // If user prefers to see in Fahrenheit, convert the values here.
        // We do this rather than fetching in Fahrenheit so that the user can
        // change this option without us having to re-fetch the data once
        // we start storing the values in a database.
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String unitType = sharedPrefs.getString(
                getString(R.string.pref_units_key),
                getString(R.string.pref_units_metric));

        for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
            // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;

            // Get the JSON object representing the day
            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
            // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
            // "this saturday".
            long dateTime;
            // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
            dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

            // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
            JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

            // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
            // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
            JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
            double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

            highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low, unitType);
            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
        }
        return resultStrs;

    }
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        // If there's no zip code, there's nothing to look up.  Verify size of params.
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        int numDays = 7;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // This will only happen if there was an error getting or parsing the forecast.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        if (result != null) {
            mForecastAdapter.clear();
            for(String dayForecastStr : result) {
                mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
            }
            // New data is back from the server.  Hooray!
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Both are actually used for the same purpose, but each should be in charge of handling menu options that they own.

As you can see the main activity and the fragment both have  `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` so the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` methods of their respective classes should handle the menu selections for their own menu items (from `R.menu.your_menu_definition`).

When a menu item is clicked, android starts going through all the classes that have provided options to the menu until it finds on that can handle the action/menu option selected by the user. This also helps to explain the return value of onOptionsItemSelected. If the function returns true, it means that the menu item has been dealt with an the framework does not need to keep looking for another class to handle the menu selection.

Comment: Okay so in the tutorial I followed the fragment takes up the entire frame of the main activity so are both methods just watching the same menu items? Thanks for your help btw, really appreciate it.